# Grails bootstrap plugin works not perfectly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am totally new to Grails. Today I try to investigate how to integrate Grails and Bootstrap.

Based on the information from here:
https://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap

I can run my simple web-app, However, every time when I start my app, I met this from console, even I can access those files from html source page:

```
2015-04-02 20:38:15,008 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js    
2015-04-02 20:38:15,080 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-button.js    

2015-04-02 20:38:15,141 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-carousel.js    
Error |    
2015-04-02 20:38:15,201 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-collapse.js
```

Comment: Sounds  like you might be using the resource plugin? I'm not entirely sure the latest bootstrap plugin still supports resources since Grails moved to asset-pipeline. You might look into that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Maybe I should delete my resource plugin from classpath, based on the info I had, all of resources are loaded by the assets.

Comment: After delete the resource plugin, it works well, thanks.